# fill array with data needed for fusioncharts

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Can someone help with with the following, im trying to fill array **$a** with data needed for my fusionchart graph. But after checking it with *var_dump()*, no data can be found.

the first query returns 6 brands, and the second query returns the sales for each brand in 2 rows. this is the format needed for my graph in [fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/stacked-charts/creating-stacked-charts.html).

```
        $datum=array();
        $a=array();

$stm3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM `weeks` WHERE `".$select."` = '".$zoeken."'"); 
$result = $stm3->execute();
$results = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



foreach($results as $row) {
$stm4 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(`sales`) AS 'sales' FROM `weeks` WHERE `".$select."` = '".$zoeken."' AND `brand` = '".$row["brand"]."' GROUP by `brand`,`datum`  "); 
$stm4->execute();
$results1 = $stm4->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results1 as $row1) {

                 array_push($a, array("seriesName"=> $row[0], "data"=>$row1));
            }
}
```

array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/stacked-charts/creating-stacked-charts.html)=> array(2) { ["seriesName"]=> string(16) "brand1" ["data"]=> array(1) { ["sales"]=> string(5) "11806" } } [2]=> array(2) { ["seriesName"]=> string(16) "brand1" ["data"]=> array(1) { ["sales"]=> string(5) "16626" } } }

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on because we don't know your data, nor variable contents. Also, the main idea behind PDO `prepare` is that you will prepare a statement with placeholders (bijv. `prepare('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... = ? AND ... = ?') and execute it passing the parameters, `execute([arg1, arg2])`. If you interpolate the variable directly in the query, you defeat the purpose of prepared statements.

Comment: foreach($results1 as $row1) {echo "$row";print_r($row);echo "<br>";echo "$row";print_r($row1);return; } see if you have any data; and also set error reporting

Comment: @sidyll please see my updated answer and tell me if it solved your problem

Comment: It didn't solve my problem yet, but it helped me a great deal!

Comment: @v Sugumar I was looking on the wrong data, you fixed it. Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define $a first.. if it not defined..

like $a = array();

if it not defined already $a is null and array_push cant add items to null..

also you are getting only associative array values using

```
$results = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but you are refering indexed array

```
array_push($a, array("seriesName"=> $row[0], "data"=>$row1));
```

change

```
$results = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$results = $stm3->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
```

Comment: Srry, had not included that part. Tnx for your anwser anyway

Comment: @KevinvanSchaijk it is better to use `$a[] = ` anyway, even the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) recommends it.